# How to scrape all div in all page of a webpage

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

The site I need to scrape has a table with the same row in all pages.
With the code I found online I can scrape only the first row.

```
<table class="players">
            <tr><th><a href="./?sort=pos&amp;order=a" rel="nofollow">Position</a></th><th><a href="./?sort=name&amp;order=a" rel="nofollow">Player Name</a></th><th><a href="./?sort=club_team&amp;order=a" rel="nofollow">Team Name</a></th><th><a href="./?sort=nationality&amp;order=a" rel="nofollow">Nationality</a></th><th><a href="./?sort=height" rel="nofollow">Height</a></th><th><a href="./?sort=weight" rel="nofollow">Weight</a></th><th><a href="./?sort=age&amp;order=a" rel="nofollow">Age</a></th><th><a href="./?sort=condition" rel="nofollow">Condition</a></th><th class=" selected"><a href="./?order=a" rel="nofollow">Overall Rating</a></th></tr>
            <tr><td class="posFW"><div title="Second Striker">SS</div></td><td class="left"><a href="./?id=7511">L. MESSI</a></td><td class="left"><a href="./?all=1&amp;club_team=%22FC BARCELONA%22&amp;sort=club_number&amp;order=a" rel="nofollow">FC BARCELONA</a></td><td class="left"><a href="./?nationality=%22ARGENTINA%22&amp;sort=national_number&amp;order=a" rel="nofollow">ARGENTINA</a></td><td>170</td><td>72</td><td>28</td><td class="condition"><img src="images/condition2.png" alt="2" /></td><td class="selected c3 lvl30">94</td></tr>
```

My code:

```
<?php
$uri = 'http://myoldsite.net/data/';    
$get = file_get_contents($uri);   
$pos1 = strpos($get, "<div title=");   
$pos2 = strpos($get, "</div>", $pos1); 
$text = substr($get,$pos1,$pos2-$pos1+3);
echo $text;
?>
```

I need to scrape: Position, Player Name, Age and Overall, with my code I can scrape only first div="title... how to scrape all rows in all pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do it in xpath by using DOM. You can get much help from http://scraping.pro/using-domxpath-for-parsing-page-content-in-php/